# Why mocking is still effective after existing a code in nosetests multiple tests?

Tags: python, nosetests

I have the following code test_A.py which mocks MyClass.mymethod:

```
from unittest import main
from mocker import Mocker, MockerTestCase
Class test_A(MockerTestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.m=Mock()
    MyClass.mymethod = self.m.mock()
    self.m.result(None)
    self.m.count(0,None)
    self.m.replay()

  def test_me(self):
    #Do something about MyClass.method

  def tearDown(self):
    self.m.restore()
    self.m.verify()
```

I also have another code test_B.py which DOES NOT mock MyClass.mymethod:

```
Class test_B(MockerTestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    pass

  def test_me(self):
    #Do something about MyClass.method

  def tearDown(self):
     pass
```

However, when I do "nosetests test_A.py test_B.py", it looks like after testing test_A.py and entering test_B.py, MyClass.mymethod is still mocked up. Not sure why and how to get around it. Thanks!

Comment: Which mocking library are you using here? Is it [mocker](http://labix.org/mocker) or [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) or something else?

Comment: from unittest import main
from mocker import Mocker, MockerTestCase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
MyClass.mymethod = self.m.mock()
```

really does replace `MyClass.mymethod()` with a new object. All subsequent references to `MyClass.mymethod` will be to the mock object, even if those references are in a different class.

What you want is a way to replace `MyClass.mymethod()` that only works in class `test_A`. The simplest way to achieve this would be to restore the original `mymethod` in your `tearDown` method:

```
Class test_A():
    def setUp(self):
        self.originalMyMethod = MyClass.mymethod
        self.m=Mock()
        MyClass.mymethod = self.m.mock()
        self.m.result(None)
        self.m.count(0,None)
        self.m.replay()

    def test_me(self):
        # Do something about MyClass.mymethod

    def tearDown(self):
        self.m.restore()
        self.m.verify()
        MyClass.mymethod = self.originalMyMethod
```